# Rect in in d3js svg disappears after routing to another page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I have a very strange behave in my angularjs application.

1) I'm using d3js to draw a nice bar chart

```
graphG.append("rect")
      .attr("id", function (d, i) {
        return "bar_" + i;
      })
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
      .attr("width", function (d, i) {
        return rectWidth(d, i);
      })
      .attr("fill", rectColor);
```

2) After a data update there is a transition

```
      barG.select("#bar_" + i)
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("fill", rectColor(d))
        .attr("width", rectWidth(d, i));
```

So far the width transition works fine. The color transitions with gradient doesn't work, but this is an another question. It changes the color but without smooth transition.

[image]

If i reroute to another page and come back the rect will not be rendered any more. The rect is in the dom. Width attribute got changes. No bar.

[image]

After F5 reload every thing is fine again.

And more strange behave: it happens in Chrome, it works fine in Firefox.

Anybody some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem:

the error was that the gradient id (return of rectColor function) was same in both directives. So it seems that there is some caching in Chrome.

Rename the gradient id in one directive fixes the issue.